# HDF5 does not support string?

Tags: export, data-structures, hdf5-format

I did a simulation for [Baccarat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccarat_(card_game)).

So some results are saved like this.

```
"1:eJytXcuSI7cRnF2tvOvP8B90A3z6Rh9Jh63W+uiTD4qYkw/y/\ 4epeexkslGJQpIXBVcxZKOBQiErK6vwl//899fffn56evr9y/U/f3/+/X+//ZP+9Sf610/\ 4r+9frx/+/dey25UjfN59fJ4Pz398I/radII/LR+f6/75+vHp+6frf/\ 728jE3jLqH34MhTXs5jALDqPX7tx//f56ev7yP45eBcRR4l+kC/78+/6ymYwPDP8Pn+\ vxVDuNzMB27j3ep13f540vR3+LzyuH5m/O8qcLv7Z7/LB43HT6GNl+\ H9uN5zeWOfgTmq1xeliqa2hksox5wdV5WZHiF8dHTkU1GmVrdBp/PnsXP+C5bnN/\ nT2L6ab8ehqwLLQrGf5TLXdcrNb7asIRTkY+b8XHnzuOilYJ9Oy/\ 0e09qgc84SjTAlxFnDe3HLE/XWaZ/rAYSLfEBLf5l749b+T74vJNzgH7g6v5Wm+O+\ 3YYTvHlxHKHV7dHiP6ZgxAzwNCvonzfS3+Bs3azETwPDwKkjh4ne53UrBF+kXYpzN79+7/\ sfc/ev48g+PK8fHtkg2syp4+QznnuDG016uGlBO/DOz/\ lEJv9VrTeODB9dOmYXzRya3eX15I4mqLRHPJePo23Izxa0ePloxDYzfjZPM5y5AqfZFUx8\ EsOo4G/qhdxlx99Es3/ClWgtfHt/\ lYVRzcgktJ08zsi81yYYQIEumE5MwrTVJoiPA8utr1979TE7dw4QTZci3W4J9sLVjj0Ejd\ v6+Irsoj/F6T91DvvoNxCWXTSAxp2+vGyP7ArToYKIUZ2l847PccurEaY6Sf+\ N4dsV6VjTWdAvnOXqIY6u5urhSXWNK+\ ReRed2oa9pnx1twIq2jkishREDILEzQWIJfrBenj+LOUBjKOj4Tx1rjvY+/\ ga6jO3rUmTCitdVe/VX+5E5OODz0KxaB1fbzVH4duwQD4ko/go9PiuLR5+9MS1+\ oV0j8RiyQsXjF+oaTqa2/vb1cS+rehhBQkghHbQVNZD18EYKTtFZQ0/\ aR5UBiI41Ml5h3r5SVgki4Wq03rLiqfAWVmVOrC5NlQlPz/Sq38Q8k7EjWwbRhQt2K+\ EWTVbC1yjI2ZpMFloaBrhVHpg4ibXaJ0fbY58kTYqH3Q3F8tlZiDlgjWcddxHWZHvw0Apv\ eem7D0zsjmyD9uFDYHmR0RbTjHTcW8HWQLxJnD5y7OchAIygFkGm5Mdxa2w9B08pDpy5RV\ OK8NZ0LpinNnqNa5TxJN4asczUe1yGot7TosmTBePIkxm+\ FZotSWVgoA1vfQ049aMj70B0yAplZzJYldMpQ5F0073TlJ4lOEfmbr7J1ehjJk9HZ5aCQP\ 3isUoYEFGEvdExGh60eNodO8dMPqIN7RaPk4tHIxExhUfmfNGRMMJJkzglaNPhFdYHzzit\ gKtzagHItkcYS8nAI9ohwnsEJCj85pBLDz7F6V1wMdqt4JCROTqasfalvU+\ q9m4UleHCnzyqeubcuqTnOHfjBSqtfHr0qnhyMiPg5dZxlptBEswmAjTz0Eb7RBvf6li0R\ jz2xmRWouxG0fqCuiaAxgM0fDQeBjsdJ6KR49c23jAIjSB+qunI/\ OrHLQ9DKECn3If46Acb3bY9WXMPLyROr7KVoSg5NIRuPQoo4dKnTkCC8Y95khETgpvrqCk\ IxHIIruoKG/6DhjGcdS0HvcuRdj25+Wze2tKp45460VJZloah0fUo/\ qpeFfdXz6lHb7olk1EMQzky5re0KyEELWctkkK3s+G8k+VYkGEkUcii5/\ wROS9yZJ2cHqKqrjwjslGMHXDBi8xjcyoCbXtjpqTw2ejWLpJdIrZgR/\ b66cd8zCPzEShxpq0kXfDAR1dbdh7pTKQlbvut9PJlDa7HOQDyqLgVNlqOeolSxebpVlgY\ o/wP8vLFzacEXErVOgqEffS1MelW80xnY9QbITqbz15qEF9l2uqY/\ AFB8hxkRHt5eMzHjCWkgyQ0J3ga9t62ceR738PTl423NaVyHSQ5BdnwtzTMOIjFY2fRatl\ HqPQuwfyXpjwRXRPBBYqvvbO+tA2vbHR++kR2YhkeZ1QwFT/\ CDIHhTT3hf6aQYEerq1wOEqWF8xOfnWFgdET+\ oJNg2gVmfPDUwzUoTnlPQESmiZt3Yct8ciyTjt5GqUS8mIGL6inbM1TYVgt4CxmjBQQJze\ /Wr51RwC6eeHuu0amgqf+SEbC73H/V3D8VtWw8b0yMCFr8QWrFeYqYJrYsnuom0K+\ VdK61FDfxRfEmghtJmw3l/jLpmw7YXAKrq0PRZhBya3U+HXkXL/VS2Lq+\ qFeNikmWVzf2ssIbF13pLFNLfTYuB1ubZWonTUwCWz577irS2/ELosqzJ4+\ hwIGnQHJzO1piizuZ16RXaIhn2jxepBZVUlxadFVfrD5tTfhGsgV06zpixD9FHZNbAHChT\ SPDdfzTsXA9RM8rwJVhZWkOTEFSI1WY0tu6OkCq9KVDUsLTAE2Wk1leiYh0kUF6GZEOZxT\ wSNScpaHVB1c1Ug3uoiUx2/\ ZPTD1GMCFR7lVLc2Wv5dwonGFiVRIyj0gjHug3JPx6tJ5Y44K6Tkrcp+PdkD/\ TJaIR9Nt5/nOOKj3fFTgJoIxT91ZCPn5oD9g1hkXFfBwzBBIZUXIYt4YX2VKZIB2+\ WoOE7SbGqCZYnPZ5VY6S5aIitaOHTqgq9rzOzqVmHzmBHruUEP9MmlwlGIynu9mKgJDRm3\ g3AYNLr+4lgRAIje8lLiLeCx2dOeHMy0kqnbOJD9C6kcF0ausQuVPs4h0nM8eq6tFkFyfO\ oFvObVpnHlPFSosJyqgIg5CRytdPwfaqi9c+hwL7E72WpK/\ RJ3JRgTUMoqEQbW81X4vDwC2zN1VRUVF8SQtGytaMv0kUr10spShplB6qugSkVtX+\ ljKsF4+/m9YCykzgW2zJRiAonpvArc87VJfpodJ9Wnqp18cYisOFW4P/\ hYYx7gyQnF1kIFF9GXvQO6VTuIG8D5edeGd+1PZE60WmB9BPc1CYODULEwP+\ hqScZl1ewGeVJh3X3E0UvZrlIxOZdF4BToTKfmVIRkYDzzQENkcdZxIHTHjifnkFlbTpCi\ sqV8Az8mjm1LritgiXoWVqk8gUAzYZwkAFb4o5CInsdLwxVBqa4ZuqZkAxrdcr40jIFSht\ oF1uJLSfTeKCCJkObzRSF5khLrRCh9Iuh6Hys3YjuffmRBkyuGzNuCmfnivBYe0Knq6GI0\ sj+Dy1Vo+MpdMF7UyPu3uL3DBeWc6F1LTFbMSHqUzMuGlhEdGKa+\ 5kuLaRZTCUCNHQINBUTsUkthtV84lEebf/yaCgtaexW8KZM2UdlCoiLyZpAgwvuAerjs+\ jLXhg8lF6GOSPzp6HIRSh26JQTs+s+\ Csb9tcK45FsFveli3mDjTLrwiBqg4QGujdF81FCXtePUFnounnceEIp3wmPKgyY9/\ zx6KGFOLc/l47DxSMHZ6PXJCYjP+mwAZwOw8nvhD3R7O/ptSUYJRG1Z/\ o16MJUtHauRtXd3TaciTQLfq46w0MNjXq8R4bLaNTcxvF6ECT2IrzoBylvjNatizKD4vRu\ PUEm99AxQMrp3l8vQg1qOmXHyI1tyW49uRupMvRrV67vsrS63PGWVk0KQjY049reYyaBsv\ bqZKdW1GZGaVqX7qZaW7hxLYY7VefOLsHXzDbGdPbkQ+\ rZ1LhE9bm1A5BJ5U6njWXKNTDlqeq1RuexG3p0O8rnbnmddpB+uyWvceADGq5Sx+\ NzWgBc9x4LR0TwTldzBb2YbY1RkNOuG5khYgNAz9XLRSaQ8LzXERfhKLOWi3qzMrH5VRsz\ hU5e8nNdgpopk5l73UYy/NVeJ3keoL/k63FWez/jJt465t1Xo9C5OIQSBcWkK/\ AkYE2zDGYxhtrQAnszvgtmvEPh4R7gwnFrNqYa+YeqI1sqSsXPbjoLlwU/\ NzvTRYfa6nuvAykjO28t4k4p828k6iOsfBN6VC3woRi81/\ AywdwVtkEpEcWTD3GaWYGIMLPqDpSU+\ hrbeUEODp9dpOKb6ATSaNzPm1JnqI6ODxcNR398gHCyUze1Zr7GQTn6zh1HWuq1p0D1+\ FaccBdarIuORZB4OJps8Zr7CmcoYuvMTvjE37AgR+1yJJxvpS+\ WvRPi5MbKsuQAz2j36h4uN5c2vr7ca3yx8XDsXIUWXExkE2Mbmi0Jptb97MfftFFYkDlXi\ 6cBmi6RqHigl0dZi1TQoNR9l4n8+\ NxpphIQVEOxwfpumVStzdbWXsKQCWGpfUtI9exRz5ShJSFtr+\ 9kcy9iCeCQ56pRuKLvCGA8yulJCx9ShrnTDI8vUPWkqJF4+Q3pZaJJinPM6JSw6Y4sWk5/\ QF92cWoiZLuJHCUVzxUyt0Z8n7vHs73TWnm/\ ZkzuUp8PNA6hazB7XGaGTpx0z1syQPe6qG6D7qAdmimjqIf2+N+\ uqkwVze3N4JviCIKLWsWC+\ 3Ixs4s12CmLdjFIozbumLsnpd1J6k9BL8Cpp7NPYKhOgWqEhYfQQ+\ NesgSuqT3dXyKMoGtLa0fEQr2ebgpp71YIF33bBJWvmGoVbjVHAYFyXdMDKqzpMq+\ TNmYcJZIQvWAzQ0Y3legBgMf04sVsAcMNhtJXQ1Ka8+QZV+HUvMxRo7sytX/\ hFZsnfcleoMh6+5ogSzPVFcRn5e9fJ0LIPEQ2gVnNe32t5Ej/\ iIRPrs0sp9k2NZH8I9qw6iknHI4raHLHVNUHv110tfuWjN9a7Uje+\ H57USJlQWc4zIBbEEoJ5c6V8Mf2Qkxuf5oDzYBMwnKTcmvdp1MEyZuKuK6nmBezBdaW42k\ pATu1bdW9qY4atfPVEoqFqqEao7od49HsFt1Fj2vfvJxl1Eusc5kWmh13XvYwxk3aQD67B\ Ms21nktYBLz2WqXfJuCQtKqDzbqC2E2WcCsdDmnCTeq7jCDBvKRuMF0yoLwHx4MJt1Mwkm\ OdRXAI7m8edX4tM45hSaCVT2MgD22jThe2jJqGFyNjbvV3OXrJnICgt3fj3eOWgx0YEWNl\ LZvPv0FU0+\ ubBHDIl3mQEkn3IPurW2UVWoZfNAp1sW1uOe55YLc89GtsWYdcTHrC2xdNTLCupkFtZkr5\ ubGaIsZTpXMKcuAQSUOCcLfWu8wR41izSo9ymPs9c0zgW1NVHT7KT0DFCHv0+t+\ K5OwXrsMaK/X3WXHvWnQnaB0uqxjZHoj23yS48gY7llvr0bzluGaTHzVAxmr9N2X9k/\ MPfQgIo1mkPB+iXVkaUNKvmjKK5lPVv3QrdCKlm1Ar0cEJwJ1U3HeqDVOyErsE/IUqx+\ yHC+XgJtdvhu19RnlOx49PZo1+\ r3g9pwONiWOkTM92uYSCW76bd2LhqTHGJi6ERqSaRftWHGyyEmZERqiQ0pI5zuvm9c4lF1\ E9i66QQhfP7DqzDqesUX27rReijhV0C5HsC8Q48tg1UYoQS10NbsWT0dm4aSzf0gLRESAx\ 3QPLt559/d3rSwweBKvPQfVkG/T/\ Cs9OhcysHhSzTmZhsn0T0EF6lw16Ro0NLYvTM8nNakKlMXlI6RfOwTRPT8JwHK18dPAo6W\ 0JLM35pO3oelQ1eqAoa5HkZEEWqZehRXOslmMSvbZkV0gcby/33tQor1z6+I+eOtN7xK6+\ PRsA8ONTp7V4Gv7HsuVkaFoiRPePjt1b58NNhIlX3oNrxrN+\ MePRoyiO7nZIB1eTiZvHXQif6tgzmiTq1k8XzkRKsOSIOitJmVeBjqocTeaJznJA8l8IfF\ aFbqMC7fWPaMy6Z86doEAwJqoT1Sn2czSHsfs5rfX1bQpaQSCJJNaoDs+\ Ojqq8HZc84qnqSsrwZW6PTjvanpRO+n0GmR6inslLpN+sGt04iWokxpMeLSzGKXTr+\ AR2AfDR846KA0XgZEdr9qXgff+eHbj2vkMgUFd/IaiuWDKO5rudZ3iOD276KRVSovKt+\ 94B3SgYJo7qUZKrRMm/TEMN9NbOLWi8ttEpIy1DW76DXLbnQx/\ 0Itq6sX0CQZt1i3EKZQ27Y+Af8PBJ8geipIe4XDR8xSdBORm9NrJZjRQt5ewqu1PXc/\ N1N/EfQUaAhqp8xlHpDhm3aiZLMNtEYnGrPs0T0OANKFNojybRmmkV0G6wbxbnkIOHEbzU\ prmRqKWjiZeZqkMYVbJio6URiUEsXXtplIE6ZFsx6PJuLmVciUNCnPc3Hc0yUoORyrAHtW\ dydFeyMwkdIiqhWAYQ1EgX90kJ3mk7WyGSqC++bItS3jjk8umEI1xbp0UQU7IPamDC2zek\ K6gYMmvjpyRzfmidqedC5yD5paP6FVXtFCGu/ESOtQzkKmm0W3yKHpZvAvSSduJh+\ hFRmJRXv0djsfVNJlwqFMKSHDUbadAtdR0bjRcWsQGoVc3eRY8fnUfOapOfURvtZOEZY3T\ dBx18v1XUjmMXs5sLMbCZ3ZH6tllTQM4+3aV2s6gD+prvXj5QaqfLhpsn+\ lVrQMJHfOs7z4nvczZbMVA5Dy3wuj0QHgwL5nvbUOk1sFMmyHSQsSuy8zmkfqHTCqXbuXW\ aVGM69+oyJfV3o9AaQpOtLIMw59qyhapoXv+\ UisSxd5IQSytAblmlqo9qXEszDDgWumkQ7T22wBPFh1XUxDoRnObth3MG52zRBDjXnW41n\ +mwmfuf/TkvDUpBTlOkqIudIvcuku7t0wone8NyDziOpVy1/\ FSteQk6i7sXnxFRSw73QBkpG1zJmnHcbUy96GbDYQmAJ+X5mkOXuw+\ 0Ho9EpvZIHTdsDJDltQeJ5fIVV+PfhWuMwm8er3/A2MdMC8="
```

When you uncompress it, it looks like this:

[image]

Exporting to Excel, it worked fine when you have small number of data, I can even add heading for column:
[image]

Each sheet in the Excel is the result for a shoe.

Is it possible to export them into HDF5?

I tried something like this

```
Export["testbig.h5", {   "shoe_1" -> tmp[[1]],   "shoe_2" ->  tmp[[2]],   "shoe_3" ->  tmp[[3]],   "shoe_4" ->  tmp[[4]]   }]
```

But it does not work.

> Export::errelem: The Export element Datasets contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to HDF5 format.

Comment: you may try something like `Export["testbig.h5", ToString@FullForm@tmp[[1]]]`, which can be read back via `Import["testbig.h5", {"Datasets", "/Dataset1"}] // ToExpression`

Comment: @egwenesedai Unfortunately, the output becomes a complete junk. I think HDF5 might not hold such dataset. So my only option now is to find a more efficient way to export to excel.